# If I update my Divi theme in my wordpress is it harmful for SEO point? My seo location is USA

Tags: wordpress, themes, seo, updates, divi

My SEO location is in USA and the niche is Education. My current theme is very old I have replace the current theme with the new version. My new version is purchased so how is the dicission from SEO point?

I want to update my current DIVI theme but thinking the effect from SEO point

Comment: I don't think, it will effect SEO. Please confirm, the old theme was also DIVI? 
The content and SEO tags will be same with new version as well.